# html. Проблемы с фоновым изображением

Tags: html

Когда делаю изображение фоном, оно размножается на экране. Как это исправить?

```
<body  background="image\1_4b06-yi.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Попробуй почитать руководства по сайтостроению моложе 1999 года

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть `background-repeat`

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: можно поподробнее, а то у меня все равно не работатет

Comment: @Дима, в CSS прописываете то, что привёл в примере, в url свою картинку

Comment: @St1myL Судя по вопросу - надо начать с объяснения того, что такое CSS

Comment: @РашенБеарб не сомневаюсь:)